# How to enable interruptable downloads on downloadable products?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, extensions, downloadable, programming

I have a downloadable product store.

My problem is that some of my files range over 1GB which is quite often, too large to download in one sitting. I want my customers to be able to pause their download session during the product download and restart at a later time.

Such as here

[image]

I've found two extensions that *claim* to do this, one at £150 that simply does not work for us. And one at £1,500 that is simply too much to pay.

I understand this is a common feature with modern browsers however we want to embed this directly into the 'Downloadable Products' tab in a magento account page. Not to mention most browsers have trouble interrupting downloads.

**My question is, are there any other extensions which are capable of this? If not how would one start with building this functionality in, programmatically?**

Edit: These are my response headers

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a complex job.  Probably better to break you downloadable products into smaller pieces if possible. (they can all still belong to one product)

Comment: If you'll pardon the reference, there are over 9000 products, so that's not an option unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

A download is an array of bytes which is sent via HTTP response.

If you would like to give it a try to extend the standard functionality, go to `app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/DownloadController.php` and check `_processDownload`.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused, give what a try?

Comment: Extending the standard functionality. Updated my answer.

Comment: My mistake, I could have worded my question a bit better. When I say 'where to start' I didn't mean the file, I meant what sort of code I could write/.htaccess modifications etc.

Thank you for the file reference and I will edit my question to be more specific